when user login the system,if he hasn't operated a long time,how to logout the system and skip to login page
I want to achieve this function:when user login the system,if he hasn't operated a long time,how to logout the system and skip to login page?
I use a filter class which implements Filter,and when satisfy a certain condition,then sendRedirect() to login page. But when i deploy the project and run it,the following issue have occurred: because the expired parameter i set is 45s,so ,after i logining into the system for 45 seconds,the request "http://localhost:8082/login" which report 200,but it doesn't skip to login page and others requests reported 302.
Here is the code :
@Component
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/com/jeeplus/*"})
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse res=(HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        String name =(String) session.getAttribute("name");
        String url=req.getRequestURI();
        //获取请求相对路径
        if(!req.getRequestURI().equals("/sys/login") && !req.getRequestURI().equals("/sys/sysConfig/getConfig") && !req.getRequestURI().equals("/sys/getCode")){
            if(Objects.isNull(name)){
//            返回登录界面
                res.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8082/login");
                return;
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
    }
}

After i login into the system for 45 seconds,i wish to jump to login page which is "http://localhost:8082/login".
